# SQL dynamic column name from PHP variable?

Tags: php, sql

```
 $db_col=$_POST['db_col']; //string
 $db_val=$_POST['db_val']; //string
 $name=$_POST['name']; //string

// connect to db

$query="UPDATE `table`.`person` SET `$db_col` = ? WHERE CONCAT(first, ' ', last) = ?;";
$stmt = $web_dbi->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $db_val, $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Getting error:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: your query failed http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and maybe a dash of http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I'm aware; do you suggest any solutions? Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: `$db_col` opens you to SQL injections. You should check that value with a whitelist.

Comment: `if(in_array($db_col, ['safe', 'columns']){ /* code */ }`

Comment: Put the following at the top of your PHP files `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and then replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$web_dbi->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and make sure your HTML form is using a POST method with same name attributes as the POST arrays. @faalbane

Comment: @Dale good suggestion

Comment: @Fred-ii- are you suggesting there's a more specific error I'm missing?

Comment: @faalbane that is exactly what I'm suggesting/thinking since we don't know which animals we're dealing with here ;-) and use `var_dump();` there may be whitespace somewhere. It could be anything really.

Comment: @Fred-ii- checked for whitespace; no unexpected whitespace

Comment: @faalbane did you try what I asked [earlier here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800567/sql-dynamic-column-name-from-php-variable?noredirect=1#comment61175376_36800567)?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, no error appeared; same console error

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL STATEMENT is incorrect:

```
$query="UPDATE `table`.`person` SET `$db_col` = ? WHERE CONCAT(first, ' ', last) = ?;";
```

the format is:

```
UPDATE table SET column = ? WHERE [conditional];
```

you have a dot between `table` and `person`, and I don't know why you have two tables next to each other when you can only update one at a time so that is another error.

If that doesn't solve the problem, do the following:

```
echo "query is: ".$query."<br>";
```

right after you write the query, and paste the output here, that way we can see exactly what the database sees and where the error lies :)

Let me know if that fixed the problem for you!